# How to use Monte Carlo method to find volume?

Tags: matlab, volume, monte-carlo

So the question asks to use the Monte Carlo method to find the volume of an irregular figure defined as:

```
0<=x<=1, 10<=y<=13, y>=12cos(x), and y>=10+x^(3)
```

I have managed to get up to this part, where I initialize a random generator between two points for x and y.

```
n = 100000;
x = (1-0)*rand(n,1); y = (13-10)*rand(n,1)+10;
```

I have no idea how to do the rest this on MATLAB.
I don't need to have a function for these methods, just line-by-line code is alright.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The book just tells you the answer to a particular problem, but it doesn't tell explain the process.

Comment: Did you converge?

Answer (score 3):

I'll show you a different example, from which you should hopefully be able to work out your problem.

I'm going to approximate the area of a circle of radius 1. Firstly, my $x$ and $y$ coordinates will range from -1 to 1.

```
n=10000;
x=(1-(-1))*rand(n,1)+(-1);
y=(1-(-1))*rand(n,1)+(-1);
```

Now one of these points $(x,y)$ is inside the circle if the distance from the origin to that point is less than or equal to 1. The distance from the origin to the point is $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, so calculate that for every point:

```
r=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2); %// note I used element-wise dot exponentiation
```

Now see which points lie in the circle:

```
countInsideCircle=sum(r<=1) %// the number of points less than one unit from the origin
```

To calculate the area of the circle, first find the proportion of points that lie in the circle:

```
proportionInsideCircle=countInsideCircle/n
```

and then multiply by the area of the surrounding square (sides of length 2, so area is 4):

```
areaOfCircle=4*proportionInsideCircle
```

I did it and got `A=3.1588` which isn't too bad as an approximation to $\pi$.

For your shape, you wont need the radius calculation, and you will just have to modify the `countInsideCricle` line to include the points you want, and also be careful about the area of your bounding box, it wont be 4.

Hint: `s=sum(0<=x && x<=1 && y>=12*cos(x))` should give you the number of points satisfying $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $y\geq 12\cos x$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean *area* rather than *volume*, because you only have *x*  and *y* dimensions.

You have already defined a rectangle that includes your irregular shape. The only need to add two simple steps:

1. Find the *proportion* of points of that rectangle. For that you can use [`mean`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html).
2. Multiply the result of step 1 by the rectangle area, which is `(1-0)*(13-10)`.

So:

```
area = mean(y>=12*cos(x) &  y>=10+x.^3)*(1-0)*(13-10);
```

is the desired result.

Note that your condition

> y>=12cos(x), and y>=10+x^(3)

is translated into Matlab as

> `y>=12*cos(x) &  y>=10+x.^3`

where `&` is logical "and" and `.^` is *element-wise* power. The result of this expression is a vector of `1` and `0` values, depending on whether the condition is met or not. So the `mean` of that vector is the proportion of points that fulfill the condition.